# In a subatomic particle the particles spin

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In a subatomic particle the particles spin on their axes as well as they rotate around the nucleus. But the question is what is the direction of rotation when viewed from one point? Is it clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: This is trivial, like a planet rotate around a star, is it clockwise for not?Both are possible. BTW its called spin up or spin down. The question that is not trivial is where ever your observation place is, still both are possible

Comment: Although the intrinsic angular momentum of quantum particles is called “spin”, there is no consistent way to model them as little rotating spheres. You should *not* think of them as “spinning on their axes”.

Comment: Is your question about electrons in an atom?

Comment: Does earth rotate clockwise? On the North Pole it does, but on the South Pole it rotates counterclockwise.

Comment: @my2cts The Earth rotates from west to east, so looking down onto the South Pole it's going clockwise.

Comment: @pm2ring correct, it is the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental particles (leptons and quarks) are, as far as can be determined, point particles with zero size.  So they cannot be thought of as actually "spinning" on their axes.

So why do people talk of spinning particles?  The reason is that electrons (and the other fundamental particles) have an intrinsic angular momentum called spin, as well as a magnetic moment.  Qualitatively, this magnetic moment is the same as that which would be generated by a classical charged sphere that was spinning on its axis.  However, quantitatively, the values are not the same: if you assume that (say) the electron was a sphere of uniformly distributed charge and mass, and calculated the magnetic moment based on the electron spin, you get a value that is off by a factor of two.  The reason is quantum mechanical, and reinforces the notion that you can't think of an electron as a classical, rotating sphere.

To get the direction of spin, you can look at energy states when an electron is placed in a magnetic field.  The lowest energy state will be when the spin is anti-aligned with the field (anti-aligned because the charge of the electron is negative).